# Que signifie « sacré + [nom] » ?

Tags: expressions, registre-familier

Après une conversation rigolote, un ami m'a dit:

> « Sacré Karlo! »

Je ne comprends pas exactement ce que signifie « sacré + [nom] » ? Sur [internet](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/sacre-1/#definition), j'ai retrouvé la définition

> *(Familier) Avant le nom, renforce l'admiration ou l'injure.*

Pourrait-on alors traduire *sacré* par *fameux* par exemple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans ce cas précis, ce serait synonyme de:

> "Ah, ce Karlo, sans lui le monde ne serait pas le même !".

Ca peut être dit de manière sympathique:

> "Ah, ce Karlo, heureusement qu'il est là ! Sacré Karlo !"

Ou de manière moqueuse:

> "Ah, ce Karlo, y'a que lui pour faire des trucs aussi bêtes ! Sacré Karlo !"

La définition que tu as trouvée correspond plutôt à l'emploi:

> "Ce type, c'est un sacré connard !"
>   "Quelle victoire inattendue, c'est un sacré retournement de situation !"

Qui a exactement le même sens que "bloody" en anglais.

"Fameux" n'est pas exactement synonyme, car il suggère une notion de renommée, qui n'est pas là avec "sacré".

Comment: +1 pour "bloody". On peut aussi utiliser l'adverbe "sacrément" : "Tu es un sacré joueur, tu as sacrément bien joué hier soir".

Comment: Ça me fait penser à la chanson « sacré charlemagne » mais pour moi l'école est fini pour l'été

Comment: Notons l'utilisation de l'adverbe *sacrément* : *Tu as sacrément raison !* = *You're goddamn right!*, *You're dead right!*, *You're bloody right!*.